# Disable download link (using HTML5 download attribute) until download completed

Tags: html, download

I have a website which has the following HTML link in it:

```
<a href="/api/admin_csv_dl" download="adminCSV.csv">Download CSV</a>
```

This works, but the API I'm using takes a while to generate the .csv file so there's a delay between clicking the button and the download starting. I would like to disable the link until the download is completed, or at least until it begins (since the download itself takes comparatively no time at all) and then re-enable it, but I don't know how to "expose" that information when using the HTML5 download attribute.

If I were using something like ajax to tap the API, I would disable the link as soon as it was clicked and re-enable it once I got a successful response, but the HTML5 download attribute is pretty nifty for my use case, except that I can't figure out how to inspect the process more closely.

Comment: How big is this file?  You could always download it via the Fetch API, then link to a Blob copy of it.  The whole file fits in memory when you do this though.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, you could keep the <a> the same as you have it now, but have it hidden so it's only used for its functionality, but not directly interacted with by the user. Then you could have a button or something that you could use to "click" the <a> when it is clicked and just disable the button, but there is no way to know when the download is finished so you could set a time out or something after doing some testing on how long it takes to download the item. This is very hacky because obviously the download time can vary massively depending on the user's internet speeds. This could look something like this:

```js
const downloadBtn = document.getElementById('download-btn');

downloadBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  // trigger download through hidden link
  document.getElementById('download-link').click();

  document.getItemById("btn").disabled = false;
  
  setTimeout(
      function(){ document.getItemById("btn").disabled = true; }, 3000);
}
```

```html
<button id="download-btn">Download</button>

<a id="download-link" href="/api/admin_csv_dl" download="adminCSV.csv" hidden>Download CSV</a>
```

That being said I would opt to do this entirely programmatically if disabling the link/button during the download is super-important. If you go this route I would look into something using the browser's `downloads` api. More info can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/download). Best of luck!